# Unable to run NVIDIA Docker image on Azure

Tags: linux, gpu, nvidia-graphics-card, docker, azure

I set up a `Data Science Virtual Machine for Linux (Ubuntu)` on Azure and want to check the installation of GPUs following [these TensorFlow directions](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/docker#gpu_support). The first command shows that a GPU is available with Tesla M60:

```
$ lspci | grep -i nvidia
db4d:00:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GM204GL [Tesla M60] (rev a1)
```

The second command fails with a cryptic message:

```
$ sudo docker run --runtime=nvidia --rm nvidia/cuda nvidia-smi
docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:348: starting container process caused "process_linux.go:402: container init caused \"process_linux.go:385: running prestart hook 1 caused \\\"error running hook: exit status 1, stdout: , stderr: exec command: [/usr/bin/nvidia-container-cli --load-kmods configure --ldconfig=@/sbin/ldconfig.real --device=all --compute --utility --require=cuda>=10.0 brand=tesla,driver>=384,driver<385 --pid=31149 /data/docker/overlay2/16e2b65fa0831681029432e3936005fa2796afd6d5a50c297d6bc0693e57a0b0/merged]\\\\nnvidia-container-cli: requirement error: unsatisfied condition: driver < 385\\\\n\\\"\"": unknown.
```

How can I set up a machine to run the Nvidia docker image?

Answer (score 0):

[This NVIDIA GitHub issue](https://github.com/NVIDIA/nvidia-docker/issues/835) and this part of the error message:

```
--require=cuda>=10.0 brand=tesla,driver>=384,driver<385
```

suggest it is a driver issue. I don't quite understand why.

## Solution using Docker, but without your image

The simplest solution is to use different Azure images: both `NVIDIA GPU Cloud Image` and `NVIDIA GPU Cloud Image for Deep Learning and HPC` will run that Docker image.

## Solution using your image, but without Docker

Alternatively, you can still use `Data Science Virtual Machine for Linux (Ubuntu)` but without the containerisation of Docker. Conda, for example, can set up an environment (where the initial `yes |` answers yes to the prompts to install the packages):

```bash
yes | conda create -n TF python=2.7 scipy==1.0.0 tensorflow-gpu==1.8 Keras==2.1.3 pandas==0.22.0 numpy==1.14.0 matplotlib scikit-learn
export PATH=$PATH:/data/anaconda/envs/TF/bin
export PATH=$PATH:/data/anaconda/envs/py35/bin
```

These commands pull the official models from Tensorflow:

```bash
git clone https://github.com/tensorflow/models.git
export PYTHONPATH="$PYTHONPATH:./models"
```

A first call to `nvidia-smi` shows that the GPU has no running processes:

```
$ nvidia-smi
Mon Jan 21 16:26:02 2019       
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 396.44                 Driver Version: 396.44                    |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  Tesla M60           On   | 0000DB4D:00:00.0 Off |                  Off |
| N/A   39C    P8    14W / 150W |      0MiB /  8129MiB |      0%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                       GPU Memory |
|  GPU       PID   Type   Process name                             Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|  No running processes found                                                 |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

When you leave the official MNIST model running in the background for a little while, you will see one process using the GPU:

```
$ python models/official/mnist/mnist.py &
[1] 25967
$ nvidia-smi
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 396.44                 Driver Version: 396.44                    |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  Tesla M60           On   | 0000DB4D:00:00.0 Off |                  Off |
| N/A   37C    P0    77W / 150W |   7851MiB /  8129MiB |     93%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                       GPU Memory |
|  GPU       PID   Type   Process name                             Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0     26077      C   python                                      7840MiB |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```